# How do I remove or hide the Permalink in comments?

Tags: theming, 8, comments

How do you remove or hide the 'Permalink' in comments? There is no tpl.php in Drupal 8. I remove `<p class="comment__permalink">{{ permalink }}</p>` from comment.html.twig, refresh, close and open my page, but nothing happens.

How I can edit the comment template file?

Comment: did you flush/clear the cache?

Comment: rebuild cache. and i hope you didn't hacked the core.

Answer (score 4):

Just tried your idea (remove `<p class="comment__permalink">{{ permalink }}</p>` from comment.html.twig) and it works as expected.

Important: Don't forget to rebuild your cache:

```
drush cache-rebuild
```

or through the UI

```
admin/config/development/performance > "Clear all caches"
```

Good luck!